# Why isn't my metallic material showing in lookdev mode?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm watching a tutorial, and the author made his sphere metallic in *Look Dev* mode and it shows. I do the same thing and it turns black no matter what I do, whether I turn on scene world or lights or keep them off (his are off).

Here are pictures of his screen: First, he turns the background all the way down;

[image]

[image]

Then he makes his ball metallic.

Here is what happens to mine:

[image]

Why is his *Look Dev* mode options different from mine, and why is mine black?

Comment: It would be easier for people to solve your problem if you could include the Blender file.

Comment: https://file.io/cOridgZUY6WA here you go

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me in lookdev mode.

Comment: thats weird ://

Comment: Feel like sharing a file?